# Error in function ProjectDetails in ./src/templates/project-details.js:7

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

**== Boring, but possibly necessary environment conditions ==**

The Gatsby tutorial by NetNinja on YouTube is quite popular on the web, I see references to the code, verbatim, all over the place. For that reason, I used the exact error as reported in my static page, on the belief that this exact error, even the line number, will have appeared for other people trying out the tutorial.

Basically, the NetNinja extended and enhanced a simple starter template, Hello World into a portfolio site.

I think the tutorial was using Gatsby 2.n or 3.n, but by the time I started it, I was using Gatsby 5.11, and at several points throughout the tutorial I had to start over and install packages immediately after rebuilding the hello-world starter project.

**== Problem description ==**

I finally got to the end of the tutorial, and could have sworn I had it working perfectly, where, when you click "Portfolio Projects" you are routed to a portfolio list. You click one of the items, and you are again routed to that particular project. Yesterday I fired up the site to show a friend, but the portfolio end page gave me the error shown in the screenshot below.

All of my pages work, except for the very last endpoint, the portfolio item:
[image: Error on line 7 of project-details.js]

**== File code with the error on line 7 ==**

```
import React from "react"
import Img from "gatsby-image"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import * as styles from '../styles/project-details.module.css'

const ProjectDetails = ({ data }) => {
  const { html } = data.markdownRemark
  const { title, stack, featuredImg } = data.markdownRemark.frontmatter

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.details}>
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <h3>{stack}</h3>
        <div className={styles.featured}>
          <Img fluid={featuredImg.childImageSharp.fluid} />
        </div>
        <div className={styles.html} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: html }} />
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
 
export default ProjectDetails

export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectDetails($slug: String) {
    markdownRemark(frontmatter: {slug: {eq: $slug}}) {
      html
      frontmatter {
        stack
        title
        featuredImg {
          childImageSharp {
            fluid {
              ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

There isn't a whole lot on this specific problem, and not being an expert in React, I don't really know how to troubleshoot the way I would if this were PHP or vanilla JavaScript.

I did `console.log(data)`, and the console shows data is undefined.

Hopefully there is somebody out there more familiar with Gatsby and React, and possibly the project I'm referencing.

**== Calling page ==**
This file is web-warrior\src\pages\projects\index.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import * as styles from '../../styles/projects.module.css'
import { Link, graphql } from 'gatsby'
import Img from "gatsby-image"

 const Projects = ({ data }) => {
 //console.log(data)
 const projects = data.projects.nodes
 const contact = data.contact.siteMetadata.contact
 
  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className={styles.portfolio}>
        <h2>Portfolio</h2>
        <h3>Projects & Websites I've Created</h3>
        <div className={styles.projects}>
          {projects.map(project => (
            <Link to={"/projects/" + project.frontmatter.slug} key={project.id}>
              <div>
                <Img fluid={project.frontmatter.thumb.childImageSharp.fluid} />
                <h3>{ project.frontmatter.title }</h3>
                <p>{ project.frontmatter.stack }</p>
              </div>
            </Link>
          ))}
        </div>
        <p>Likewhat you see? email me at {contact} for a quote!</p>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
}
 
export default Projects

// export page query
export const query = graphql`
  query ProjectsPage {
    projects: allMarkdownRemark(sort: {order: DESC, fields: frontmatter___date}) {
      nodes {
        frontmatter {
          slug
          stack
          title
          thumb {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
        id
       }
    }
    contact: site {
      siteMetadata {
        contact
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates that the `data` variable is undefined, therefore you cannot access `data.markdownRemark` and deconstruct the `html` property from it.

Basically the component `<ProjectDetails data={data}/>` receives data that is undefined, or does not receive it at all. Make sure that the prop is passed correctly. I cannot help you with this since I don't know what data is or where you are rendering ProjectDetails.

here are some things you can do:

1. Search for `<ProjectDetails` component in your project. You need to find the file where you are rendering that component
2. Check if  data is being passed and is not undefined `<ProjectDetails/>`  -> `<ProjectDetails data={...?}/>`
3. Find where the data is being passed from and ensure that it is not undefined or that you are actually passing the correct thing.
4. If you find the source of the problem, post an update so we can look into it.

Comment: I've been working with your answer. It turns out there is no `<ProjectDetails` per se, but I am updating my question with the code in the file that invokes ProjectDetails.

Comment: @TARKUS Try searching for ```ProjectDetails``` .  It might be found as an element of route props. It looks like ```Projects``` has links that lead to the page that renders ```ProjectDetails``` elements. You need to find the route that is rendering the ```ProjectDetails```